# XNA problem when draw many different batches

Tags: xna, 2d

I have a 2D game in 4 directions, and I'm having problems with FPS (or GPU) because I have to draw a lot of textures.
I've read a lot about techniques to optimize performance, but I don't know what I can do anymore.

The main problem is that in some occasions I have about 200 creatures, where I have to draw his body (it is a single sprite) but also draw spells and other animations on his body. 
So, I think that is when it starts to give conflicts because the loop where I draw each creature, must change the textures for each creature, that is body>animation1>animation2>animation3 and this about 200 (creatures) times at 60 fps. Which lowers the fps to about 40-50.
Any suggestions?

This is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably - as you have already suggested - the constant switching between different textures. This is much slower than drawing the same number of sprites with the same texture.

To change this, consider putting all your textures into a single big texture. You then always draw that texture. This obviously would look quite wrong, so you also have to tell XNA which part of the texture you want to draw. For that, you can use the SourceRectangle parameter that can be passed to SpriteBatch.Draw(...). That way, you can always render the same texture but can still have different images on screen.

See also [this answer about texture atlasses](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/82872/29311) for more details.